# Render IFrame in JSF page based on condition

Tags: jsf, iframe, jsf-2, richfaces, rendering

We are using iFrame to display reports generated in the application on the GUI.
The report is correctly displayed on the GUI within the iframe.
However, on certain button click I want the iframe to disappear(render=false). But to my utter disbelief, this is not happening.

Once iframe is rendered on the page, it is not getting rendered=false unless I refresh the entire page.

The iframe is placed inside `<rich:layoutPanel>`.
I tried keeping iframe inside `<h:panelGrid>` and `<h:panelGroup>` and rendered it using there render property however the iframe itself was not coming up.
When it came, even when render attribute of `<h:panelGrid>` was set to false, the iframe was not being rendered=false.

I understand that iframe will create a separate DOM against the existing DOM for the entire page but there should be some way out to render the iframe based on certain button click.

Code snippet for iFrame:

```
<h:panelGroup id="checkIFrame" rendered="#{Bean.renderPanelGroup}">
    <iframe frameborder="0" align="left"
        src="${pageContext['request'].contextPath}/moduleName/PageName.jsf"
        name="PdfPnl" id="PdfPnl" scrolling="auto" width="750"
        height="500" marginheight="5" marginwidth="10">
    </iframe>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Code snippet for button on clicking which, the iframe should be rendered=false

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="outButton">
    <a4j:commandButton value="Send" immediate="true" status="Hello" 
        rendered="#{Bean.renderTrueFalse}" reRender="outButton,checkIFrame"
        id="Again" process="FormName" actionListener="#{bean.affirmative}"
    />
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

How can I render the iframe=false/true based on some button click?

Answer (score 5):

You can't reRender a component that has a rendered attribute defined on it. You need to reRender a parent component of checkIFrame that has no rendered attribute defined on it.

UPDATE:

```
<h:panelGroup id="aParentPanel">
     <h:panelGroup id="checkIFrame" rendered="#{Bean.renderPanelGroup}">
         <iframe frameborder="0" align="left"
             src="${pageContext['request'].contextPath}/moduleName/PageName.jsf"
             name="PdfPnl" id="PdfPnl" scrolling="auto" width="750"
             height="500" marginheight="5" marginwidth="10">
         </iframe>
     </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>

...
<a4j:commandButton reRender="aParentPanel".../>
```

...

Comment: If i rerender a parent component of checkIFrame which has no rendered attribute attached , then how can I hide the checkIFrame on button(a4j) click...My sole purpose is to hide iframe on button(a4j) click..

Comment: You can keep the rendered attribute on checkIFrame panel. It will work as expected. Just rerender another parent component without rendered attribute.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer..However the solution provided is not working..The iframe itself is not getting displayed..Infact the pdf opens up on new page...

Comment: this is another different problem. what browser are you testing on? try using an <embed id="pdf" src="..." type="application/pdf"/> instead of an iframe

Comment: I am using Mozilla firefox 14.0...I will try the <embed> tag now to see if it is working..

Comment: No.it's not working..It is again opening in new page..Firstly, the panel displays even when page load,but without any report.When I fire an action listener the report opens up in new tab and the panel remains as it is in old tab..